# Using subdependencies in npm script

Tags: node.js, npm, scripting, package.json, bin

Say I have a private npm package, `@myprivate/repo` which has the following contents in its `package.json`:

```
 "scripts": {
    "example": "db-migrate"
  },
  "bin": {
    "foo": "bin/foo"
  }
```

Where `bin/foo` is:

```
#!/bin/bash
npm run example
```

I now pull this into a parent repo with npm install:

package.json:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@myprivate/repo": "*"
   },
   "scripts": {
     "example": "unrelated command",
     "useful": "foo"
   }
}
```

Then running `npm run useful` results in the `foo` bin script getting called, which then attemps to call `unrelated command`. How do I scope the invocation to the dependency? How can I force a bin script to package its own npm dependency and rely on that? Is nested `scripts` in nested dependency `package.json` the best way, or is there a better more canonical solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up being able to get the behaviour I want by changing the last line of `bin/foo` to:

```
npm explore @myprivate/repo npm run example
```

This does feel a little bit happy (I'm referencing the repo using npm explore from within itself), but it does get the job done. Would love to hear of a better solution